# How to implement a callback in C# to retrieve return code from a native DLL method with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, .net, dll, callback

I need to call a native method of an unmanaged DLL From C#.
DLL source code is not available of course (provided by a "third party").

Native DLL method is supposed to accept two arguments and returns a (native) integer code:

> MyDLLNativeMethod(string filename, int returncode)

The first argument of native DLL method is a string (filename) & second has to be a "reference" to gather return code after execution. I'm confused about how to get return code. DLL calls are working properly, producing expected files based on first argument.

How should I implement the desired callback to perform operation on different return codes values retrieved?

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Main entry point
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
namespace MyProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDLLCaller _dllcaller = new MyDLLCaller();
            _dllcaller.MyDLLNativeMethod("test_file.txt");
        }
    }
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// DLL calling class
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    namespace MyProject
    {
        class MyDLLCaller
        {
            // DLL Loading    
            [DllImport(@"C:\test\mydll.dll")]
            public static extern int MyDLLNativeMethod(string _filename);

            // Native DLL method pseudo code :
            // MyDLLNativeMethod(string filename, int returncode).
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return code is the second parameter I think you should use `out` keyword for this:

```
int returncode = 0;

[DllImport(@"C:\test\mydll.dll")]
public static extern int MyDLLNativeMethod(string _filename, out int returncode);

if(returnCode != 0)
{
    // something went wrong
}
```

Try it with some file that you know should return error code.

Answer (score 0):

If the above declaration for the external call works with your library, you get the return code from the call.

```
var retCode = _dllcaller.MyDLLNativeMethod("test_file.txt");
```

Comment: Using declaration above: `public static extern int MyDLLNativeMethod(string _filename, out int returncode);` now Visual Studio complains about `"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter returncode` when calling this method with only "_filename" parameter : `_dllcaller.MyDLLNativeMethod("test_file.txt");`